# Logos in Migration list should have empty 'alt' values (instead of "icon for <domain>")

Tags: bug, design, migration, accessibility, alt-text

When voting to move a question with "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network", a list of sites is shown, where each entry consists of the site logo and the site name/link (e.g., "belongs on stackoverflow.com").

Currently the `img` element for the logo has an `alt` value like this:

> icon for stackoverflow.com

**It should have an empty `alt` value instead**, because in this context the logo doesn’t convey relevant information, as the following text already states which site the radio option is about.

So instead of

```html
<img class="cp" src="http://stackoverflow.com/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="icon for stackoverflow.com">
```

it should be

```html
<img class="cp" src="http://stackoverflow.com/apple-touch-icon.png" alt="">
```